# How do i use to calculate the value of todays date in sharepoint 2010 list to find date +0?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise

I have a list  built in sharepoint 2010 which contains date column. I need todays date should be automatically fills that column when adding new item in the list.

for e.g: if the todays date is "1" i need to fill that field as 001,  but if the todays date 11 i need to fill that field as 011.

What type of column i can select? How can i achieve my requirement?

Comment: Hi, it seems your accept is 0%. If answer was helpful, you're supposed to "accept" it (click check mark next to this answer, below the rating buttons). This will encourage site experts help you more eagerly and also it will indicate the answer as a correct one, so that other users will know that the solution is correct. Please read our FAQ for more details: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 2):

You can use Calculated Field as lgaud said and then use following Formula:

`=CONCATENATE("0", TEXT([Today],"dd"))`

This should work!

[Reference URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx)

Comment: Please mark the correct answer!

Comment: Hi Arsalan, The first 6 digits would come from the current day’s date.the last 3 digits would start at 001 and increment throughout that day. So if the date is 03/12/13 the first list value number will be 031213001 and the second should be 031213002. Is it Possible? How can i achieve it?

Comment: Post a new question, I will answer there! Also accept the answer on this question by marking the tick mark

Comment: I have created new question.Please you can check in this link.http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/65398/how-to-calculate-the-value-of-sharepoint-list-field-in-the-date-field-column/65412?noredirect=1#65412

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it using a [Calculated Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx). The syntax is mostly like Excel, so you can sort out your formula there.