# How to calculate the Value of sharepoint list field in the Date field column?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

The first 6 digits would come from the current day’s date – the last 3 digits would start at 001 and increment throughout that day. So if the date is 04/11/13 the first  value of the list should be will be 041113001.

What type of column i can select? How can i achieve my requirement?

Comment: so you mean the auto-increment column will reset the other day and start from 1 again ?

Answer (score -1):

First Create one Auto increment column check this below link

http://gihanmaduranga.blogspot.in/2012/09/create-auto-increment-number-column-in.html

After that create One more Calculate column here you can bind Two Columns (DATE+Auto Increment Column)

=Text([DATE Column],"DDMMYYYY")+[Auto Column]

Second Option Fully OOB

Created Two Calculated Columns and one Date column

First is Auto Column
[image]

Second one is DateAuto (mix of date and autonumber)
[image]

let me if you have know any difficulties......

Comment: The requirement says about auto increment on daily basis. Both the solution you provided will not satisfy this requirement.